# Install haxe and neko.dll

Tags: flash, haxe, swfloader, haxelib

I tried to execute haxe.exe but I get an error : "The program can't start because the neko.dll is missing from your computer." I look in the Environement Variables and there the path for NEKO is corect. I installed version 2.9 of haxe, I tried to reinstall the app but the problem persist. I use the windows 7. Help me please!!!

Comment: Is there a reason you're installing such an old version? 2.9 was released 3 years ago :) I'd try a new version, and see if it gives the same message: http://haxe.org/download